# Find common line in two files and replace the next line of first file with the next line of other file

Tags: perl, bash, sed, awk, grep

I want to find common lines in two files and replace the next line of the first file with the next line of second file. Sed, awk, Perl, Bash, any solution is welcomed.

The comparison is case-insensitive and there can be multiple occurrences of the same line.

File 1:

```
         hgacdavd
sndm,ACNMSDC
msgid "Rome"
msgstr ""
kgcksdcgfkdsb
msgid ""
hsdvchgsdvc
msgstr ""
dhshfjksdfhmd
msgid "Vidya"
msgstr ""
sdjhcbnd
dcndnv
cfnkdndvrknvkf
dfkvrnkdfnk
snfvrkng
msgid "Rome"
msgstr ""
wdbhkjbcfj
#dmcdmf
f,nvdf,

fvnfnvk
vfmf,mv
vfn

msgid "vid"
msgstr ""
dmcbdmbcvmfbvmkhsdk
```

File 2:

```
  dfhkvgjbfrvkf  
msgid "Rome"
msgstr "new bie"
sdbsjbcdcbwoido
fjcdcvnm
msgid "vidya"
msgstr "expert"
dvnjfkdvhnkfvnknsbdjh


msgid "vid"
msgstr "newton"
dfenfjdbrfjbvlfnvl
dcnkncvkdfvknfv
fcndkbvknfkv
vfdnkvnfknbvkfn
```

Later, file 1 should be:

```
          hgacdavd
sndm,ACNMSDC
msgid "Rome"
msgstr "new bie"
kgcksdcgfkdsb
msgid ""
hsdvchgsdvc
msgstr ""
dhshfjksdfhmd
msgid "Vidya"
msgstr "expert"
sdjhcbnd
dcndnv
cfnkdndvrknvkf
dfkvrnkdfnk
snfvrkng
msgid "Rome"
msgstr "new bie"
wdbhkjbcfj
#dmcdmf
f,nvdf,

fvnfnvk
vfmf,mv
vfn

msgid "vid"
msgstr "newton"
dmcbdmbcvmfbvmkhsdk
```

Comment: Using grep ,I am able to find common lines in both the files.. but then I dont know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Version 1 of question:

In this version of the question, the lines with msgid and msgstr appear in pairs and are separated from other lines with a blank line.  Here is a one (long) line solution for this case:

```
$ awk -F'"' 'BEGIN{RS="\n\n";OFS=""} NR==FNR {c[tolower($2)]=$4; next} {print $1,"\"",$2,"\"",$3,"\"",c[tolower($2)],"\"\n"}' file2 file1
msgid "Rome"
msgstr "new bie"

msgid "Vidya"
msgstr "expert"

msgid "Rome"
msgstr "new bie"

msgid "vid"
msgstr "newton"
```

**MORE:** The version below updates file1 with the new information:

```
$ awk -F'"' 'BEGIN{RS="\n\n";OFS=""} NR==FNR {c[tolower($2)]=$4; next} {print $1,"\"",$2,"\"",$3,"\"",c[tolower($2)],"\"\n"}' file2 file1 >tmp && mv tmp file1
```

**How it works:**  Let's break it down into parts.  The first part is just setup:

```
$ awk -F'"' 'BEGIN{RS="\n\n";OFS=""}
```

To understand the above, one needs to know that `awk` breaks a file up into 'records', and then it breaks records up into 'fields'.  The above says that every time a blank line appears (two newline characters in a row), treat what follows as a new 'record'.  In other words the record separator is two newlines: `RS="\n\n"`.  It also says that records should be broken up into fields according to the appearance of a double-quote: `-F'"'`.  Finally, it says that, when printing our output, do not add any additional spaces to what we have.  In other words, the output field separator is the empty string: `OFS=""`

The next part is:

```
... NR==FNR {c[tolower($2)]=$4; next} ...
```

This says that, while reading the first file name given (`file2`), create an associate array (like a dictionary) called `c`.  The keys for the array are the msgid's.  The values are the msgstr's.  Thus, `c[rome]=new bie`.  We apply `tolower` to the msgid's so that all the keys are consistently lower case.  The `next` command means that.

The `NR==FNR` part above probably looks obscure.  To understand it, one needs to know that `awk` counts the number of records that it has seen and assigns that value to `NR`.  It also counts the number of records that it has seen from the file that it is currently reading and assigns that to `FNR`.  So, when we are reading the first file, it follows that the two are equal: `NR==FNR`.  When `awk` starts reading the second file, then `NR>FNR` and the block of code will be skipped.

The last part is:

```
... {print $1,"\"",$2,"\"",$3,"\"",c[tolower($2)],"\"\n"}' file2 file1
```

This part is executed when we start reading the second file (`file1`) and consists of just one print statement.  It prints the msgid line, including the quotes around the msgid: `$1,"\"",$2,"\""`.  And, it also prints out the msgstr, looking up the value of the msgstr in the our associative array `c` and putting quotes around it and a newline character at the end:  `"\"",$3,"\"",c[tolower($2)],"\"\n"`.

#### Version 2 of question:

In this version, the msgid and msgstr lines are not necessarily adjacent.  Consequently, every time we run across an msgid line, we save its value to the variable `id`.  When going through file2, we look for msgstr lines and store their value in the associative array `c`.  Then, when processing file1, we substitute `c[id]` in msgstr lines:

```
awk  -F'"' 'NR==FNR && $1=="msgid " {id=tolower($2)} NR==FNR && $1=="msgstr " {c[id]=$2} NR==FNR {next} $1=="msgid " {id=tolower($2)} {if ($1=="msgstr ") print "msgstr \"" c[id] "\""; else print $0}' file2 file1 >tmp && mv tmp file1
```

Comment: Thank U John,but My output file and file1 is same. How to make changes in file1 itself?

Comment: @user3273311 The answer is now updated with a version that overwrites the old file1 with the new data: see the section marked "__More__".

Comment: Thant working fine if my file1 and file2 contains only msgid and msgstr, but its not working for file which contains random value in between

Comment: @user3273311 You are right: the new version changes everything.  I developed a solution for the new version and added it to the answer.

Comment: Hi John, Can you provide implementation details for following logic:    `Search msgstr "" pattern in file1,
       take its previous line, find this line in file2, 
if found then replace the next line of file1 with next line of file2`

Comment: @user3273311 That sounds very similar to the first version of this question.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/msgid/{$!N;s|(.*)\n(.*)|/\1/I{n;s/.*/\2/}|}' file2 | sed -rf - file1
```

Turn `file2` into a sed script which is run against `file1`.

The script turns the line beginning `msgid` and the following line into a command that matches the `msgid` and then prints that line and replaces the next with the contents of the second line from the script file.

Comment: My output file and file1 is same. How to make changes in file1 itself?

Comment: @user3273311 that would suggest that there are no matches of `msgid` bewteen the two files.

Comment: Hi John, What i was asking is..instead of getting output on command prompt, can we replace the next line of matching line in file1 only?   eg: msgid "Rome" matches, then next line of file1 is replaced by msgstr "new bie" ,in file1 only..

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use this app I wrote by php. It solved the same problem.
2. Input: need to 2 files:

   - file 1: like dictionary for the 2nd file
   - file 2: like destination for getting the pair "msgid/msgstr" from file 1 if it's existing.
3. Output: as well as you mentioned

Check my source code here! 
https://github.com/NguyenDuyPhong/merge_two_po_files 
Connect to main page by the link: .../merge_two_po_files/web (Ex: http://localhost/merge_two_po_files/web )